# Is there anything like OS X's "browse all versions" to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, backup

I don't mean the [opposite question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53117/is-there-anything-like-system-restore-for-mac-os-x). And [Previous Version of files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions) isn't enough: once a day? I want more!

[image: Mac's automagic file versioning]

Sure, it doesn't have to be that cute. It can look like windows. But it needs to work at least as good as that (or [dropbox'es pack rat](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113/en), or some [automated git](http://gitolite.com/articles/backup-and-sync-with-git.html), etc) and be simple / free / automated.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

The frequency of System Restore is controlled by a pre-existing task in the Task Scheduler  (since Vista).

Open Task Scheduler and head to `Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> System Restore`.

There will be a task named "SR" with "Multiple triggers defined".  Edit the triggers for that task as you wish.

[image: Task Scheduler showing SR]

[More info here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-how-often-system-restore-creates-restore-points-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: So much for how to geek consistency... *It seems* like whoever wrote the article I've found (on my answer) had no idea about this one!

Answer (score -3):

## Beware

If by any chance you got here without noticing, *techie007* already provided [a much better answer, above](https://superuser.com/a/649838/28411).

### Legacy Answer

Not quite that simple to setup, but maybe the best answer you'll get: automate the system restore point creation. "Simply" set up a scheduled task using [this VisualBasicScript file](http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/CreateRestorePoint.zip):

```
'Written By: Jason Faulkner
'HowToGeek.com

'Usage:
' CreateRestorePoint [Restore Point Title]

strDesc = "Automatic Restore Point"
Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments
If oArgs.Count > 0 Then strDesc = oArgs(0)

WScript.Echo "Creating Restore Point: " & strDesc

Set oRestorePoint = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:SystemRestore")
strResult = oRestorePoint.CreateRestorePoint(strDesc, 0, 100)

If strResult <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error " & strResult & ": Unable to create Restore Point"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Restore Point created successfully."
End If
```

Copied from [the howtogeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/):

1. Create a new **Scheduled Task** which **runs as an administrator** on the respective machine. Make sure you have the **Run with highest privileges** box checked.
2. In the **Triggers tab**, configure how often you want a restore point created. Remember, snapshots of files are captured as part of the System Restore Point.
3. In the **Actions tab**, configure the task to run the `CreateRestorePoint.vbs` script.
4. In the **Conditions tab**, select the option to **Wake the computer to run this task**.
5. In the **Settings tab**, select the option to be able to **run the task on demand** as well as the option to **run the task as soon as possible after a missed schedule**.